# Java:output Strange in printstream

Tags: java

why output so strange 0022 =18?
hello everyone to day i have test.the question is "what is the output of

```
System.out.println(0022);
```

i so confuse why Answer is 18

explain needed

Answer (score 5):

If the first digit of an `int` literal is `0`, Java interprets the number in octal (base 8).